# How do I set command line arguments in install4j that are to be passed to my main

Tags: java, encryption, install4j

I'm encrypting my properties via custom code in install4j. I need to pass that encryption key to my main and I would like to try it via command line arguments. However, I cannot see any straight-forward way of setting an argument. Any tips on setting command line arguments in install4j would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to save the encryption key to an installer variable and mark it as a response file variable, for example by setting the "Register for response file" property "Set a variable" action.

In your application, you can call

```
com.install4j.api.launcher.Variables.getInstallerVariable("variableName")
```

to retrieve the variable value.

Comment: Which would you consider more secure, the method you've mentioned or an obfuscated keystore?

Comment: I would not consider an encryption key that is saved without a password to be secure under any circumstances, whether obfuscated or not. So I would say that is doesn't matter.